# PDF jQuery Flip book plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have been surfing the net for hours now, there are many jquery flip book plugins that works using content in HTML or with images. But I need a plugin that can use PDF to load pages in the flip book & it has to work on IE 8 as well so no HTML5.
If anyone know such a plugin please let me know, I don't want to use flash as it isn't flexible enough for my work.

Comment: Did you find source code of marco's demo link?!

Answer (score 6):

Version 4 http://www.turnjs.com/

Version 3 https://github.com/blasten/turn.js

Appears v4 has a different license.

PS: The old demo link is 404.

Comment: where to get the documentation for that plugin?

Comment: @Marco C. Did you do the PDFJS and the TurnJS combo demo?

Comment: @Marco this Demo having issue in IE and Opera. Please resolve it.

Comment: Hi, I did not create the demo, just found it surfing the web. I remember I did some reverse eng to understand the implementation, here's a thread I've found right now, you might want to check it out: https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/89

Comment: This page is blocked by service provider

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [library to convert PDF to flipbook with jquery](https://heyzine.com). You just need to include the library and call the plugin like this:

```
<a title="Demo" subtitle="Test" showdownload href="https://heyzine.com/files/uploaded/bf8cb8abcd9f0c6da8680e6bdf1b7bf0cfb7ca51.pdf">example</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://heyzine.com/release/jquery.pdfflipbook.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').pdfFlipbook();</script>
</script>
```

You can also check the demo here: https://heyzine.com/site/demo

Answer (score -1):

There are some PDF to flipbook converters/software available which offers Flash and HTML5 both. If anyone tries to access the digital edition on a cell phone or any other platform which do not support flash, then the digital edition automatically serves HTML5 for the best flipping effect.

Not sure if you have tried some of the followings.
http://smashfreakz.com/2012/09/jquery-page-flip-book-plugins/
http://www.enough.pro/best-5-jquery-flipbook-plugins/

I hope you can customize the code if need additional functionality.

Answer (score -2):

The FlexPaper Zine viewer does precisely what you're after. It also degrades gracefully when it is not able to use HTML5 so that older browsers also have a chance of viewing your publication

You can have a look at it here:
http://devaldi.com/zine/NZ_Tourism_2007.php?ro=html5,flash

Here's more info on licensing etc:
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/flexpaper_flip_zine.jsp